# Store part of code as string in table and execute as code at runtime

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table of Airline Bookings ("BookingData") and a table of conditions that have to be met in order to get a commission paid on those bookings ("Berichte.cdp.INT_PLB_IN_14321230_CommissionData as Data_Comission"). The Data_Comission Table is filled by importing Data from an Excel spreadsheet to MS SQL Server 2016.

For most airlines the rules are straightforward and fall into one of 4 categories ("Data_Comission.RuleID").

The following code works fine for those 4 rules:

```
select 
            *
            -- Define Commission IDs ----------------------------------
            ,case 
             when BookingData.BookingClass ='0' 
                 then 0
                 else
                    case (select distinct Data_Comission.RuleID from Berichte.cdp.INT_PLB_IN_14321230_CommissionData as Data_Comission where Data_Comission.AirlineKrz = Bookingdata.AirlineKrz)
                    when '1' -- no Rules on ServiceClass, BookingClasses_included, BookingClasses_excluded
                        then (select distinct Data_Comission.LeadCommission_ID from Berichte.cdp.INT_PLB_IN_14321230_CommissionData as Data_Comission where Data_Comission.AirlineKrz = Bookingdata.AirlineKrz)
                    when '2' -- Only BookingClasses_included
                        then 
                            case
                            when BookingData.BookingClass IN (select Data_Comission.BookingClasses_Included from Berichte.cdp.INT_PLB_IN_14321230_CommissionData as Data_Comission where Data_Comission.AirlineKrz = Bookingdata.AirlineKrz) 
                                then (select distinct Data_Comission.LeadCommission_ID from Berichte.cdp.INT_PLB_IN_14321230_CommissionData as Data_Comission where Data_Comission.AirlineKrz = Bookingdata.AirlineKrz)  
                                else 0 
                            end
                    when '3' --Only BookingClasses_excluded
                        then
                            case
                            when BookingData.BookingClass IN (select isnull(Data_Comission.BookingClasses_excluded,'0') from Berichte.cdp.INT_PLB_IN_14321230_CommissionData as Data_Comission where Data_Comission.AirlineKrz = Bookingdata.AirlineKrz)
                                then 0
                                else (select distinct Data_Comission.LeadCommission_ID from Berichte.cdp.INT_PLB_IN_14321230_CommissionData as Data_Comission where Data_Comission.AirlineKrz = Bookingdata.AirlineKrz)
                            end
                    when '4' --BookingClasses_excluded and ServiceClass_Index
                        then
                            case
                            when BookingData.BookingClass IN (select isnull(Data_Comission.BookingClasses_excluded,'0') from Berichte.cdp.INT_PLB_IN_14321230_CommissionData as Data_Comission where Data_Comission.AirlineKrz = Bookingdata.AirlineKrz) 
                                then 0
                                else (select distinct Data_Comission.LeadCommission_ID from Berichte.cdp.INT_PLB_IN_14321230_CommissionData as Data_Comission where Data_Comission.AirlineKrz = Bookingdata.AirlineKrz and Data_Comission.ServiceClass_Index = BookingData.ServiceClass_Index)
                            end
                    end

             end as ComConditionID
        from
            (

            select
                -- a lot of stuff from the BookingData tables --
            ) BookingData
```

The problem is some Airlines have special rules that are not easy to capture through a fixed set of rules. Some examples:

```
case
when Bookingdata.AirlineKrz = 'BR' Then 
    case when BookingData.IsExIndia = 1 then 19 else 20 end
when Bookingdata.AirlineKrz = 'CA' Then 
    case when (BookingData.aCountry = 'IN' and BookingData.zCountry = 'IN') then 0 else 21 end
when Bookingdata.AirlineKrz = 'JL' Then 
    case when (BookingData.zCountry IN ('JP','UA','KR','CA','AU')) then 65 else 0 end
end
```

I want to avoid having to return to the code everytime an airline changes the "special" rules to hardcode them airline by airline.

What I would like to do instead is store those statements as a string (e.g 'case when (BookingData.zCountry IN ('JP','UA','KR','CA','AU')) then 65 else 0 end') in the Data_Comission Table in a column named "Rule_5_Code" and execute them as code at runtime - something like this:

```
select 
            *
            -- Define Commission IDs ----------------------------------
            ,case 
             when BookingData.BookingClass ='0' 
                 then 0
                 else
                    case (select distinct Data_Comission.RuleID from Berichte.cdp.INT_PLB_IN_14321230_CommissionData as Data_Comission where Data_Comission.AirlineKrz = Bookingdata.AirlineKrz)
                    when '1' -- no Rules on ServiceClass, BookingClasses_included, BookingClasses_excluded
                        ...
                    when '2' -- Only BookingClasses_included
                        ...
                    when '3' --Only BookingClasses_excluded
                        ...
                    when '4' --BookingClasses_excluded and ServiceClass_Index
                        ...
                    when '5' --Special Rules
                        then execute ((select distinct Data_Comission.Rule_5_Code from Berichte.cdp.INT_PLB_IN_14321230_CommissionData as Data_Comission where Data_Comission.AirlineKrz = Bookingdata.AirlineKrz)
                    end

             end as ComConditionID
        from
            (

            select
                -- a lot of Stuff from the BookingData tables --
            ) BookingData
```

I have run into two problems:

1. The code (Column Rule_5_Code) is not imported from Excel to the SQL
   Server (where Column Rule_5_Code is defined as nvarchar(max)), the
   error is something like (translated from german) "The text was
   truncated, or one or more characters had no equivalent on the target
   code page".
2. I have no idea on how to actually get the string to execute as code

Is there a way to make my idea work or am I completely off the track and need a different solution? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Storing T-SQL, in a column, which needs to be executed is (for lack of better words) a terrible idea. It can, and likely will, lead to injection problems unless there is incredibly tight controls on how the data is inserted, how it's validated, and then again when it's executed. The only way you could then get that SQL to run would be with Dynamic SQL, which for stuff like this is far from desired. Keep the logic in the actual written SQL, not stored as a `nvarchar` in a table. If you need to use the logic frequently, then a iTVF (or inline Scalar Function if on 2019+) would work well here.

Comment: to say it simple - you are completely off the track. First problem can be solved by expanding the column size during import; but you have to remember that nvarchar(max) is 8000 characters, so if your "rule" is longer than that you will need to refactor. Second problem is more problematic and comment from Larnu is a good one. .. you could also easily solve this by expanding [Country] table by adding [NumericCode] column, where you could store those 65, 19 and whatever else you want...

Comment: Larnu, thank you for pointing out the security risks in this approach, which i shall abandon in favor of hardcoding those special cases.

User2065377 - can you expand on your idea on how to solve this using additional columns?